# Get the duration of .m3u audio

Tags: swift, avplayer

I want to play audio by the URL
https://wortcast01.wortfm.org/appfiles/wort_210715_080006buzzthu.m3u

it has a body(with tracks)

```
https://wortcast01.wortfm.org/pitch/preroll-buzzthu.mp3
https://wortcast01.wortfm.org/mp3/wort_210715_080006buzzthu.mp3
```

When I set https://wortcast01.wortfm.org/appfiles/wort_210715_080006buzzthu.m3u to the AVPlayer then the duration is equal to Nan. But each track from the list has a duration.

**Do you have an idea how to extract duration via AVPlayer?**

return Nan:

```
var itemDuration: Double? {
    return currentItem?.duration.seconds
}
```

Comment: Show the lines of code where you open and play back audio.

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation(AVPlayer, AVAsset....) automatically marks any .m3u like "Live broadcasting" (my assumption: It looks like Apple uses scenario M3U8 for working with M3U)
Solution:
Create additional functionality which loads m3u(or pls) content, create an internal playlist, and play these internal parts ar AVPlayer.